How to set axis limit to a dateoffset from now in Vega Lite
How can you set the axis limits dynamically so that it always shows say until today + 90 days. I managed to to define the axis limits based on years
"scale": {"domain": [{"year": "year(now())"}, {"year": "year(now())+2}"]}

but what I am looking for conceptually is something like this
"scale": {"domain": [{"year": "year(now())"}, {"date": "now() + dateOffset(days=90)"]}

Here's a simple example in Vega Editor
I searched documentation and googled a fair bit but did not manage ti find a solution.
Also it looks like "month" doesn't accept an expression while "year" does, the code below doesn't work.
{"year": "year(now()) + 1", "month": "month(now())"}

see the example

One day is  1000*60*60*24
   {
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"date": "2024-02-15", "value": 100},
      {"date": "2024-05-15", "value": 90},
      {"date": "2024-06-15", "value": 125}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "point",
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
    "x": {
      "field": "date",
      "type": "temporal",
      "scale": {"domain": [{"year": "year(now())"}, {"expr": "now()+ ((1000*60*60*24)*90)"}]}
    }
  }
}


Thanks @davidebaccci for the swift answer. It led me to a working version with some changes, see here. I also edited your answer accordingly as the posted version did not work
